# Vue/Node error : Rule can only have one resource source

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack

I am brand new to Vue and Node and everything was going well with a Vue3 project I was messing around with to learn. I wanted to use scss files so installed sass-loader via npm using:

```
npm install sass-loader sass webpack --save-dev
```

And since then the app is broken, now when I try to serve I get the following error:

```
     Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude) in {
  "exclude": [
    null
  ],
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "C:\\pathtoapp\\node_modules\\cache-loader\\dist\\cjs.js",
      "options": {
        "cacheDirectory": "C:\\pathtoapp\\node_modules\\.cache\\babel-loader",
        "cacheIdentifier": "43be597c"
      },
      "ident": "clonedRuleSet-38.use[0]"
    },
    {
      "loader": "C:\\pathtoapp\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\lib\\index.js",
      "options": "undefined",
      "ident": "undefined"
    }
  ]
}
Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude) in {
  "exclude": [
    null
  ],
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "C:\\pathtoapp\\node_modules\\cache-loader\\dist\\cjs.js",
      "options": {
        "cacheDirectory": "C:\\pathtoapp\\node_modules\\.cache\\babel-loader",
        "cacheIdentifier": "43be597c"
      },
      "ident": "clonedRuleSet-38.use[0]"
    },
    {
      "loader": "C:\\pathtoapp\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\lib\\index.js",
      "options": "undefined",
      "ident": "undefined"
    }
  ]
}
```

I looked up this error and most believed this to be an issue with webpack but I have uninstalled and installed again. Installed an earlier version of webpack, tried changing package.json to point to an earlier version, tried anything I can currently find on SO and now I'm completely stumped.

Any assistance on this would be much appreciated as I'd rather learn and discover how to fix the problem should I encounter it again rather than simply start a new project. Let me know any code/files I should post in an edit where required.

Comment: Can you include your complete Webpack config ?

Comment: @Seblor sure, where shall I pull this from?

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue and I was able to resolve it by:

```sh
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

[Source](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8277#issuecomment-728287702)